# Получить текущее время и установить часы и минуты в конкретное значение

Tags: golang

Подскажите, как легким движением руки получить текущее время и установить в нем часы и минуты в конкретные значение? В пакете time не нашел ничего похожего. Только вариант с созданием нового:

```
n := time.Now()                                                         
t := time.Date(n.Year(), n.Month(), n.Day(), 14, 56, n.Second(), 0, time.Local)
```

Comment: А так не работает: ``n := time.Date(n.Year(), n.Month(), n.Day(), 14, 56, n.Second(), 0, time.Local)``?

Comment: Это да, но я надеяйлся найти что-нибудь по типу метода set для часов и минут.

Comment: Не вижу в пакете `time` подобных сеттеров. Думаю, вариант с `Date` вполне преемлим.

Answer (score 0):

В time можно выставлять формат времени уже по готовым значениям или можно создать свой

Чтоб установить свой формат он должен соответствовать требованиям
По ссылке указаны константы форматов и описание как создать свой формат https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    Test2()
}

func Test2() {
    t := time.Now()

    log.Println(t.Format(time.RFC1123))
    log.Println(t.Format(time.ANSIC))

    personformat := "2006 02 01 15:04:05"

    log.Println(t.Format(personformat))
}
```

Вывод

```
2022/08/09 14:27:11 Tue, 09 Aug 2022 14:27:11 MSK
2022/08/09 14:27:11 Tue Aug  9 14:27:11 2022
2022/08/09 14:27:11 2022 09 08 14:27:11
```